# How to Install wvdial.deb?

Tags: 10.10, installation

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 but unable to connect my ZTE MODEM (CDMA MODEL: AC 682). Then I tried to install `wvdial.deb` from my local drive but it showing message (`E:File not found`) invain to install.

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can [install wvdial](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wvdial) from the Software Center. Are you sure you need to install that wvdial.deb? Did you follow a guide to install your modem? If yes, please share the URL, so people can tell you which steps you can omit (or do somehow different).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)